# JavaScript: Array reverse and join is not working as expected for empty tokens in join() method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to reverse a string and applying join() method on the reversed contents in JavaScript. The join works properly when I use "-" or any other symbol in the join() method. But when I use just ("") or (" ") , it simply joining original array and not the reversed one. Please help me to understand the actual behavior.

Consider the below code.

```js
var a = [1,2,3]; //actual array
console.log(a.reverse().join("-")); // working as expected. output: "3-2-1"
console.log(a.reverse().join(""));  //not working as expected. output:"123"
```

Thanks,
Dhinesh

Comment: As written ind the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse "Reverse is destructive. It also changes the original array."

Comment: just adding to the first comment... So you reversed your array two times... making it look like the second `a.reverse()` didn't work properly, while it reversed already reversed array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Reverse**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) mutates original array

> The reverse() method reverses an array in place. The first array
>   element becomes the last, and the last array element becomes the
>   first.

You can make a shallow copy in this case and than use `reverse`

```js
var a = [1,2,3]; //actual array
console.log([...a].reverse().join("-")); // working as expected. output: "3-2-1"
console.log([...a].reverse().join(""));
```

Comment: `a.slice().reverse()` is better I think rather than creating a shallow copy.

Comment: @MaheerAli that does the same thing only [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 1):

`reverse` reverse the elements in the original array.

> The reverse method transposes the elements of the calling array object
>   in place, mutating the array, and returning a reference to the array.

```js
var a = [1,2,3]; //actual array
console.log(a.reverse().join("-")); // working as expected. output: "3-2-1"
console.log(a.join(""));  //working as expected. output:"321"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's only a problem of working on the same array and doing two times the reverse operation. Let's try doing this:

```js
var a = [1,2,3]; 
const reversedArr = a.reverse();
console.log(reversedArr.join("-")); 
console.log(reversedArr.join(""));
```